# soundcloud api resolve issue after oAuth

Tags: javascript, oauth, soundcloud

I am having what I hope is an easy to solve problem with the Soundcloud API using JavaScript:

unauthorized, the following code works fine:

```
var group = 'https://soundcloud.com/groups/chilled';
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:49957/tn/callback.html'
});
// Resolve works fine and gives number ID of group 
SC.resolve(group + '?client_id=' + client_id).then(function (g) {
    console.log('Group 1: ' + g.id);
});
```

after I authorise a user:

```
SC.connect().then(function () {
    return SC.get('/me');
}).then(function (me) {
    authUser = me.id
});
// Resolve no longer works and i get 401 unauthorised 
SC.resolve(group + '?client_id=' + client_id).then(function (g) {
    console.log('Group 1: ' + g.id);
});
```

can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong - I can't seem to find an example to follow anywhere. Driving me potty!

Many thanks in advance,

James

Comment: Maybe you are missing the client_secret information? have a close look at https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication

Comment: @Michael, it makes no difference when I include the client_secret token [value not shown]. 

SC.resolve(group + '?client_id=' + client_id+ ';client_secret=' + client_secret).then(function (g)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else out there facing the same issues, I have answered my own question:

Firstly, I was not properly logged in due to an error on Soundcloud's sample code in their callback.html used to return to the site after oAuth client side login flow. In Soundcloud's sample callback.html, the code:

```
    <body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

must be altered to:

```
    <body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

This allows the popup to close properly and completes the login flow if the application settings are correctly configured to the same domain (localhost or production, but not a mix of the two).

Further to this callback, i have added the following code:

```
        var params = getSearchParameters();

        window.opener.oAuthToken = params.code;

        function getSearchParameters() {
            var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
            return prmstr != null && prmstr != "" ? transformToAssocArray(prmstr) : {};
        }

        function transformToAssocArray(prmstr) {
            var params = {};
            var prmarr = prmstr.split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
                var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
                params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
            }
            return params;
        }
```

In my subsequent pages, I can get any data as a sub-resource of the '/me/...' endpoint now, but anything I used to be able to interrogate via public access is still in accessible. Since I can now iterate through the logged in users groups, I no longer have to resolve the name of a group via the public resource '/resolve/', so my issue is not solved, but avoided in my current development.